# Empty clusters in K-means clustering

Tags: cluster-analysis, bioinformatics, k-means

When applying K-means clustering we are picking k initial clusters and then iterating through all the points and assigning them to some cluster and also updating the centers of the clusters. Eventually we do not do any other update. Yet I noticed that sometimes we end up with some empty clusters, in the examples I've done usually this is done in the last iteration. Is this always the case? Is it possible for an empty cluster to become non-empty at some later iterations after it becomes empty?

Edit: Different from a relevant question that was previously asked, I want to know if there is a way to prove or disprove that once it becomes empty it cannot become nonempty.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11075272/k-means-empty-cluster

Comment: I believe that does not exactly answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason why this would happen late. It can happen very early too.

Clusters can become non-empty again, if you leave them as they are.

Comment: I could visualize that in my head. For instance if the center of a certain cluster close to that empty cluster is relocated after an iteration. Then some point in that cluster (whose center was relocated) could be closer to the empty cluster and hence it might join it. Yet I am not sure how I could come up with a more formal proof.

Comment: The formal proof will probably simply consist of an example. But it is of little interest to prove this theoretically.